# Correcting mistakes in questions/answers

Tags: discusión, preguntas

If I find a question written in Spanish by a Spanish learner that has some clear mistake, what should I do?

I mean, obviously I can edit the question, but I think this way the correction is very likely to be ignored by the OP, mainly for *newbies*... And I think it´s good to correct mistakes just for making the site better, but what I think is the most important is to make the OP realise his/her errors...

Maybe a comment would be fine? Or an edit along with a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the primary goals of Stack Exchange is to "make the Internet a better place." This is done, in large part, by providing high-quality questions and answers.

To that end, if you see a mistake, *correct it*.

If you believe that a lesson can be learned by the OP, I suggest also politely bringing attention to your edit and your reasoning, in the comments.

Only commenting is not ideal, as that leaves the post in a poor state, which can cause confusion, and lead to [broken windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).